# Создание web-интерфейса прибора на asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-сервер

Есть плата с микроконтроллером, которая подключается к компьютеру по com-порту и передает на него данные. Необходимо реализовать возможность визуализации данных от контроллера и его управлением через web-интерфейс.

В данном случае не важно какая именно плата с микроконтроллером. Допустим, снимаются показания с датчиков и передаются по com-порту на компьютер на котором развернут сервер для сбора данных.

Подскажите, можно ли используя технологию asp.net создать web-интерфейс для устройства с микроконтроллером? Если да, то как в таком случае получить данные от контроллера?

Comment: asp.net предназначен для создания веб интерфейсов, потому создать веб интерфейс на нем можно. А вот как подключаться к контроллеру - это уже отдельный вопрос, никак не относящийся к asp.net. К вопросу о получени данных с контроллера - обращайтесь к производителю контроллера.

Comment: хотелось бы знать тип платы, и ее возможности, скорее всего на ASP.net (по крайней мере на самой плате) задуманное вами сделать не получится. Вообще при прошивке платы вы скорее всего используете либо конфигуратор, либо пишите чистым C, через некий конфигуратор. Следовательно про поддержку C#  речи не идет. Как вариант конфигурировать контролер так что-бы передавались команды и значения поверх программного протокола передачи данных на сервер где будет крутится ваш сайтна ASP.net.

Comment: @tym32167 я подозреваю что речь идет об Arduino, и какую-нибудь сетевую плату для него. Там есть поддержка HHTP v1.0, но нет, как вы правильно заметили, поддержки динамических языков формирования страниц.

Comment: @Monomax ну я бы не стал гадать, пусть автор всю нужную инфу пишет в вопросе, пока что там вообще непонятно о чем идеть речь.

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен, поэтому в вашем первом и моем первом комментарии, и звучит просьба предоставить больше данных!

Comment: @Monomax ну, тогда готовим попкорн и ждем :)

Comment: @tym32167, обновил вопрос. Проще говоря - к компьютеру подключено устройство, которое управляется по com-порту. И вот к этому устройству я и хочу сделать web-интерфейс. То есть сервер-прослойку между устройством и web-браузером клиента

Comment: @swd "получить данные от контроллера" - это никак не связано с asp.net. А вот уже после того, как вы сможете получить эти данные, вы можете их отобразить в качестве веб-интерфейса с помощью asp.net.

Comment: @Andrei Khotko, если не сложно, можно подробнее? C asp.net я не работал. С контроллером я общаюсь через win-form приложение. Каким образом связать моё приложение и web-сервер?

Comment: скажем так - winforms приложение - это какой то код, который использует окна, чтобы общаться с юзером. Веб сервер - это код, который использует веб интерфейс, чтобы общаться с юзером. Потому если говорить в общем случае, веб сервер может делать с контроллером всё то же самое, что и winforms приложение, и если вам повезет, то даже код связанный с взаимодействием с портом менять не придется.\

Comment: @swd ниже вам дали ответ на ваш вопрос. Про создание веб-интерфейса с помощью asp.net в интернете есть достаточно информации. затем вам нужно будет взять часть кода из WinForms, которая отвечает за соединение и общение с контроллером, и правильным образом вставить в серверную часть.

Comment: @tym32167, я создал web-приложение с mvc-шаблоном. В Main пытаюсь создать объект SerialPort, но этого класса нет в подключенном пространстве имен System.IO.

Comment: Наверно потому что класс [`SerialPort`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.7.2) находится в сборке `System.IO.Ports.dll` ?

Comment: @tym32167, это я знаю. Видимо пространство имен System.IO, которое подключается в asp.net проекте и System.IO.Port, подключаемое в winform находятся в разных dll. После создания com-порта вопрос можно считать закрытым. Буду благодарен за содействие в подключении нужного пространства имен. В меню Add references я могу выбрать только Project, Shared Project или путь к конкретной dll. Нету пункта Assemblies в различными сборками.

Comment: Вы не можете найти её в списке либ потому что её там нет, она доступна из [nuget пакета](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/)

Comment: Интересная полемика, но в действительности все просто, для на чала вам просто надо создать библиотеку, которая будет отвечать за соединение с вашим устройством, и отдачу данных, все, а у же в проекте ASP.Net, конектить эту библиотечку и работать с ней.

Comment: @tym32167, Спасибо! Опубликуйте ответ, что бы можно было поставить плюс

Comment: @Monomax, Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net предназначен для создания веб интерфейсов, потому создать веб интерфейс на нем можно. А вот как подключаться к контроллеру - это уже отдельный вопрос, никак не относящийся к asp.net.

Winforms приложение - это какой то код, который использует окна, чтобы общаться с юзером. Веб сервер - это код, который использует веб интерфейс, чтобы общаться с юзером. Потому если говорить в общем случае, веб сервер может делать с контроллером всё то же самое, что и winforms приложение, и если вам повезет, то даже код связанный с взаимодействием с портом менять не придется.

Для подключения использования класса [`SerialPort`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.7.2) который назходится в пространстве имен [`System.IO.Ports`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports?view=netframework-4.7.2) необходимо полключить nuget пакет [`System.IO.Ports`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/)

Comment: А я все равно считаю что код взаимодействия с платой/контроллером и пр. должны быть в проекте библиотеки, а веб интерфейс, от рисовка и пр, должно быть в проекте сайта/страницы, так легче работать будет.

Comment: @Monomax ничего не имею против этого, тоже думаю, что разделить ответвенности будет хорошей идеей.